# Cannot remove specific key: value from YAML file

Tags: java, hashmap, yaml

**Goal**: I want to remove specific key and its associated value from a YAML file.

**Expected Result**: `orginalRef` key and it's value should be removed from the YAML file and should generate a new YAML file.

**Actual Result**: `orginalRef` value under the `responses` property doesn't remove.

**Error messages**: There are no error messages.

**What I have tried**: I have a swagger YAML file, I just load it into Jackson ObjectMapper and trying to do the removing of some keys from that YAML file. Then generate a new YAML file with the changes I have made.

**Code**:
below is a section my huge YAML file. It's name is `api.yaml`

```
---
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  description: "Planner application is a proposal system enables user to create, manage\
    \ plan .  \nIt also enables network user to publish plan "
  version: "1.0"
  title: "Planner API"
  contact:
    name: "API team"
    email: "apiteam@test.com"
  license:
    name: "Copyright © 2020 test
host: "aos-dev.test.com"
basePath: "/unifiedplanner"
tags:
- name: "Additional Fee APIs"
  description: "Additional Fee Controller"
- name: "Condition APIs"
  description: "Condition Controller"
paths:
  /v1/{apiKey}/entity/{entityId}:
    post:
      tags:
      - "Condition APIs"
      summary: "Save New Conditions Entity"
      operationId: "saveNewConditions"
      consumes:
      - "application/json"
      produces:
      - "application/json"
      parameters:
      - name: "Authorization"
        in: "header"
        description: "Authorization"
        required: true
        type: "string"
      - name: "apiKey"
        in: "path"
        description: "API Key"
        required: true
        type: "string"
      - in: "body"
        name: "conditions"
        description: "Conditions Entity that needs to be saved"
        required: true
        schema:
          $ref: "#/definitions/Conditions"
      - name: "entityId"
        in: "path"
        description: "Entity ID"
        required: true
        type: "string"
      responses:
        "200":
          description: "OK"
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/Conditions"
            originalRef: "Conditions"
      deprecated: false
    put:
      tags:
      - "Condition APIs"
      summary: "Modify / Overwrite existing Conditions Entity"
      operationId: "modifyConditions"
      consumes:
      - "application/json"
      produces:
      - "application/json"
      parameters:
      - name: "Authorization"
        in: "header"
        description: "Authorization"
        required: true
        type: "string"
      - name: "apiKey"
        in: "path"
        description: "API Key"
        required: true
        type: "string"
      - in: "body"
        name: "conditions"
        description: "Conditions Entity that needs to be updated"
        required: true
        schema:
          $ref: "#/definitions/Conditions"
      - name: "entityId"
        in: "path"
        description: "Entity ID"
        required: true
        type: "string"
      responses:
        "200":
          description: "OK"
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/Conditions"
            originalRef: "Conditions"
      deprecated: false
definitions:
  AbstractCondition:
    type: "object"
    properties:
      externalTrafficSystem:
        $ref: "#/definitions/ExternalTrafficSystem"
        originalRef: "ExternalTrafficSystem"
      id:
        type: "string"
      version:
        type: "integer"
        format: "int64"
    title: "AbstractCondition"
```

As you can see I just want to remove `originalRef` key and it's value from the `responses` property in the above YAML file.

Below is my YamlProcessor.java class which does all the necessary things.

```
package com.aos.tools.aostool.yaml;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

@Service
public class YamlProcessor {

    public YamlProcessor() throws IOException {
        process();
    }

    public void process() throws IOException {
        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());

        final Map<String, Object> api = objectMapper.readValue(new File("api.yaml"),
                new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
                });

        final Map<String, Object> path = (Map<String, Object>) api.get("paths");
        processPath(path);

        // write YAML file
        final Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        objectMapper.writeValue(new File(date.toString() + "api-updated.yaml"), api);
    }

    private void processPath(final Map<String, Object> paths) {
        paths.entrySet().forEach(path -> {
            if (null != path) {
                final Map<String, Object> level1Child = (Map<String, Object>) path.getValue();
                if (null != level1Child) {
                    level1Child.entrySet().forEach(method -> {
                        final Map<String, Object> methodValues = (Map<String, Object>) method.getValue();
                        methodValues.entrySet().forEach(methodValue -> {
                            if (null != methodValue && methodValue.getKey().equals("parameters")) {
                                final List<Object> paramValue = (List<Object>) methodValue.getValue();
                                paramValue.forEach(paramValueChild -> {
                                    if (null != paramValueChild) {
                                        final Map<String, Object> paramMap = (HashMap<String, Object>) paramValueChild;
                                        paramMap.entrySet().forEach(k -> {
                                            if (k.getKey().contains("schema")) {
                                                final Map<String, Object> schema = (HashMap<String, Object>) k.getValue();
                                                // this line works fine , this will remove all the originalRef keys under parameters property
                                                schema.remove("originalRef"); 
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                });
                            }

                            // this is where I'm currently getting stucked.
                            if (null != methodValue && methodValue.getKey().equals("responses")) {
                                Map<String,Object> value = (HashMap<String,Object>) methodValue.getValue();
                                if(value.containsKey("200")) {
                                    value.entrySet().forEach(k -> {
                                        if(k.getKey().contains("schema")) {
                                            Map<String,Object> responseSchema = (HashMap<String,Object>)k.getValue();
                                            responseSchema.remove("originalRef");
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When I run the application , It works fine without any errors. Also generating new YAML file.
but in the new YAML file, there is still originlaRef key contains under the responses property.
Anyone guide my What I'm doing wrong here.
Any help would be highly appreciated.
Cheers! Good day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I was able to get the desired output by experiment with my code.

below is the working solution for me.

```
if(value.containsKey("200")) {
    value.entrySet().forEach(k -> {
        Map<String,Object> responseSchema = (HashMap<String,Object>) k.getValue();
        responseSchema.entrySet().forEach(a -> {
            if(a.getKey().contains("schema")) {
                Map<String,Object> reSchema = (HashMap<String,Object>)a.getValue();
                reSchema.entrySet().forEach(c -> {
                    if(c.getKey().contains("items")) {
                        Map<String,Object> innerSchema = (HashMap<String,Object>) c.getValue();
                        innerSchema.remove("originalRef");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating the content of value, not value.200

```
 if(value.containsKey("200")) {
          value.entrySet().forEach(k -> {
```

should probably be

```
 if(value.containsKey("200")) {
          value.get("200").entrySet().forEach(k -> {
```

In any case, you could put log statements inside the loops for debugging such things.

Comment: value.get("200").entrySet() , this doesn't exist under the value.get() method.

Comment: So you say from your code, HashMap does not have a get(key) Method?

Comment: yes, when I tried to access the .entrySet() method from value.get() method, It didn't allow me.

Comment: You have to cast.